# Iterate over files in multiple directories without sorting

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a dataset with the following structure :

```
Dataset
│
└───Audio
│   │   _dl--eQ6qVU_1.wav
│   │   0h-zjBukYpk_1.wav
│   │   03bSnISJMiM_1.wav
│   
└───Video
│   │   _dl--eQ6qVU_1.mp4
│   │   0h-zjBukYpk_1.mp4
│   │   03bSnISJMiM_1.mp4
```

I wrote a piece of code to iterate over files in all the dataset directories using `os.walk()` and store the filename in a list based on his extension.

```
    audio_files = []
    video_files = []

    # Walking through the dataset directories and subdirectories and storing the paths
    # in separate lists.
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(data_path):
        for file in filenames:
            if file.endswith('mp4'):
                video_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
            else :
                audio_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

However, I notice that the filenames get sorted (ASCII order) automatically : `03bSnISJMiM_1` then `0h-zjBukYpk_1` then `_dl--eQ6qVU_1`.
 Is there a way to access the files as they were ordered in the original dataset : `_dl--eQ6qVU_1` then `0h-zjBukYpk_1` and finally `03bSnISJMiM_1` ?

Comment: What do you mean by the order of the dataset? Filesystems don't generally give you control over the order of files in direectories. If you don't sort by some objective criteria, they'll be in an unpredictable order.

Comment: In the dataset directory, the file `_dl--eQ6qVU_1.wav` comes before `03bSnISJMiM_1.wav`. However, as mentioned above, when I use os.walk(), filenames automatically get sorted with ASCII order so I end up having  `03bSnISJMiM_1.wav` before `_dl--eQ6qVU_1.wav` in the `audio_files` list for example. Let me know if I was able to explain my issue.

Comment: How do you know what order they are in the dataset directory? The `ls` command also sorts the names, unless you use `ls -f`. But why would you write code that depends on that order in the directory, since there's no way to control it?

Comment: If you want some other order, I recommend you write your own sorting function that does this.

Comment: My goal was to map the files with their labels (a column of a csv file) which has a specific order. The first intuition was to align the filepaths with their corresponding labels, but as you mentioned we can't control the order in the directory. I guess a better solution would be to extract the file paths and sort them based on the csv file order. Thanks for the explanations